# Append items in a for loop- jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding a simple toggle button through Javascript. Then I want to add three span tags inside it.

So, I am creating variable of span and trying to append it inside our very own basic FOR loop. Iteration count is 3 times.

Here's my basic code below. Please let me know what has been missing or misplaced that my span tag refuses to append more than once. I checked this in the inspect mode.

Then, I brought up console tab and the value of *i* was 3. Append is meant to **append** and NOT ***replace*** the element. Right ?

```
var $navbar_header = $('<div class="navbar-header"></div>');

var $button = $("<button></button>");
var $span = $('<span class="icon-bar"></span>');

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   $button.append($span);
 }

$button.addClass('navbar-toggle');
$navbar_header.append($button);
$("#menu").append($navbar_header);
```

Here's a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/x5jj0zpy/) to fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DOM is a tree, where any element points to its parent (see [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)). An element can have only one location. So when you append an element, you're removing it from its precedent location.

The solution here is either to clone the element:

```
$button.append($span.clone());
```

or just to create it in the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $button.append('<span class="icon-bar"></span>');
}
```